# JsReport client render report with Basic auth

Tags: jsreport

I have a issue using a JsReport www.jsreport.net.

In the server I enabled the Basic authentication to protect report editor, but the templates now are only accessed by authentication.

In the web page, I use ember.js and pass the options to jsreport.render, but I get error "Unauthorized".

I pass the btoa in header but dont works.

See an example:

```
jsreportInit = function(){
jsreport.render($("#contentReport"), renderPage("html"));

$("#generateExcel").on("click", function(){
    jsreport.render(renderPage("html-to-xlsx"));
});

function renderPage(type){
    var data = {
            headers: {
                "Authorization" : "Basic xpto" 
            },
            shortid : "${shortId}",
            recipe: type, 
            engine: "jsrender",
            options: {
                id : "${id}",
                questions : "${questions}",
                skipQuestions : "${skipQuestions}",
                eventPersons : "${eventPersons}",
                subscribers : "${subscribers}",
                urlApi: "http://${pageContext.request.serverName}:${pageContext.request.serverPort}${pageContext.request.contextPath}",
                urlReport: "${urlReport}"
            }
    }
    return data;
}};
```

Someone can help me?

Tks.

Comment: This is in client/browser side? Can you share that particular piece of code?

Comment: Yes. This is in client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not supported to pass headers to browser's `jsreport.render` calls at this moment. There are two reasons:

1. It won't be safe because this way you would be revealing the credentials in the browser and everybody can easily find it out
2. `jsreport.render` uses mostly synchronous http posts (form submit) which are not allowed to carry custom headers

I'd recommend to rather route all the requests through your server and hide jsreport securely behind it.

Alternatively if you are only interested in blocking templates edits in the editor, you can take a look at [jsreport freeze extension](https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-freeze)

Comment: Tks. This answer helped-me so much.